# How can i compute the number of internal edges of a community?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

How can i compute `the number of internal edges of a community`,
i was declare python program to identify community one value and two value with iterate, like this `one = 1,2,3,4,8` and `two = 5,6,7`

List neighbors:

```
4 = [2,3]
6 = [7]
3 = [2, 4, 1, 8]
7 = [5, 6]
8 = [3]
1 = [3]
5 = [7]
2 = [3, 4]
```

Program:

```
pembangkitan : [4, 6, 3, 7, 8, 1, 5, 2]

def neighbors():
        nodes = []
        nb = []
        
        for i,j in g.edges(pembangkitan):
            nodes.append(i)
                
        for i in list(dict.fromkeys(nodes)):
            nb.append(i)
            for n in list(g.neighbors(i)):
                if n not in nb:
                    print(i,n)

neighbors()
```

Output Program:

```
4 2
4 3
6 7
3 2
3 1
3 8
7 5
```

[graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywc3P.png)

[top up saldo paypal](https://jualsaldo.com)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. Hint: "I cannot compute XXX" is NOT a valid description of an issue (nor is "XXX doesn't work" etc)...

Comment: See the picture and you know what i mean

Comment: No I don't know what you mean, which is why I ask you to read those links and edit your question with all needed informations. Or you can ask a fortune teller, of course...

Comment: Agree! It's not really clear what your input is (no parameters in `neighbours()`), what certain variables do, e.g., `g` and `pembangkitan`, and what the desired output should be.

Comment: Oh i know, okay i was declare neighbors bro, thanks for your informations. g is the graph for my picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can just count the edges in the subgraph induced by nodes in the community:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([(1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4), (3,8), (5,7), (6,7)])

communities = [[1,2,3,4,8], [5,6,7]]

for clist in communities:
    community_graph = g.subgraph(clist)
    print(community_graph.number_of_edges(), list(community_graph.edges()))
```

produces the output:

```
5 [(1, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 8), (2, 4)]
2 [(5, 7), (6, 7)]
```